# Import Error, Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Hello I am working on a converting mine django app to django cms 3.0.
After I have connected mine django app, installed third party apps, done syncdb, migrate etc, and go whit runserver, I have encounter this Error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/

Django Version: 1.6.11
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('djangocms_admin_style',
 'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'cms',
 'menus',
 'sekizai',
 'mptt',
 'djangocms_style',
 'djangocms_column',
 'djangocms_file',
 'djangocms_flash',
 'djangocms_googlemap',
 'djangocms_inherit',
 'djangocms_link',
 'djangocms_picture',
 'djangocms_teaser',
 'djangocms_video',
 'south',
 'reversion',
 'djangotocms',
 'social_auth',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'djangotocms.django_app.project_template',
 'djangotocms.django_app.profiles',
 'djangotocms.django_app.pricing',
 'djangotocms.django_app.blog',
 'djangotocms.django_app.contacts')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/views.py" in details
  74.     page = get_page_from_request(request, use_path=slug)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/page_resolver.py" in get_page_from_request
  116.     page = get_page_from_path(path, preview, draft)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/page_resolver.py" in get_page_from_path
  72.         return get_page_queryset_from_path(path, preview, draft).get()
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/page_resolver.py" in get_page_queryset_from_path
  32.         admin_base = admin_reverse('index')
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/urlutils.py" in admin_reverse
  101.         current_app=current_app
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  507.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in app_dict
  329.             self._populate()
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  290.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  315.             self._populate()
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  290.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  315.             self._populate()
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  303.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  230.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  32.         result = func(*args)
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  101.                     not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/cms_daryl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /en/
Exception Value: No module named contacts
```

Can someone please tell me what am I missing here?
Tank you.

This is tree of mine project:

```
Djangotocms
├── djangotocms
│   ├── django_app
│   │   ├── blog
│   │   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   │   ├── views.py
│   │   │   └── views.pyc
│   │   ├── contacts
│   │   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   │   ├── forms.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   │   ├── views.py
│   │   │   └── views.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── pricing
│   │   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   │   ├── views.py
│   │   │   └── views.pyc
│   │   ├── profiles
│   │   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   │   ├── views.py
│   │   │   └── views.pyc
│   │   └── project_template
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── __init__.pyc
│   │       ├── settings.py
│   │       ├── settings.pyc
│   │       ├── urls.py
│   │       ├── urls.pyc
│   │       ├── wsgi.py
│   │       └── wsgi.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── fullwidth.html
│   │   ├── home.html
│   │   ├── navbar.html
│   │   ├── sidebar_left.html
│   │   └── sidebar_right.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
├── media
├── project.db
├── requirements.txt
├── static
├── untitled.sublime-project
└── untitled.sublime-workspace
```

Comment: What is `djangotocms`?

Comment: By the way, you need to change the order of your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Allauth imports should come *before* Django CMS

Comment: it is mine cms app name

Comment: Then the error is with your CMS, not Django CMS. There's no module named `contacts`

Comment: What do you mean, djangocms is mine cms app root name, and django_app is mine folder where I have stored mine django applications

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the directory structure of your project and apps??

Comment: shure, just give me a moment

Comment: It seem's I have some problems whit making tree out off mine project, I will fix it as soon as possible. Can you hint me where and what should I look please, tnx.

Comment: I have manage to share mine tree, fill free to pop in any time @rnevius